# jQuery .val() yielding undefined right after setting

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inside my Javascript I have the following code (edited for brevity):

```
var data = {
    ...
    listtoken: $(this).attr('data-token')
}

$("#qtip-search-"+ data.listtoken +"-content .search-input").val("example");
console.log($("#qtip-search-"+ data.listtoken +"-content .search-input").val());
```

The `console.log` returns undefined, yet if I run the same statement in Chrome's console it yields `example`.

Anyone know why this might have happened? The JavaScript is definitely firing after the HTML has been loaded, and the log statement works in Chrome's console, but inside the code it outputs `undefined`.

Comment: What is `$(this)` referencing in `data` ? Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: And a stack snippet or jsFiddle would be helpful.

Comment: I'm guessing that element isn't loaded by the time your javascript runs. Is your js inside a `ready` block?

Comment: @guest271314 It matters not, even if the data.listtoken is hardcoded the problem occurs.

Comment: @gengkev This is with me setting $ = jQuery in Chrome console.

Comment: @FuzzyTree Yes, inside both a $(document).ready() and a $(window).load()

Comment: _"It matters not, even if the data.listtoken is hardcoded the problem occurs."_ ? If `$(this)` is referencing `data` object , does `data` object have `.attr` method defined ? Can include `html` at Question ? , create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @user3893820 Even if you're sure that the script runs after the page has loaded, try putting it inside a `window.setTimeout` block and waiting for a few more seconds.

Comment: Is it something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/56zt9rqc/

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` appears to reference `data` object at `listtoken: $(this).attr('data-token')` , not a jQuery object ? If `data` does not have property `.attr` , would return `undefined` ?

Not clear if `this` is set to a jQuery object or element at another property of `data` not included at Question ?

```js
var data = {
  listtoken: function() {console.log(this, $(this).attr())}
}

data.listtoken()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

---

```js
var data = {
  listtoken: function() {console.log(this); return this},
  attr: function() {console.log(this.token)},
  token: 123
}

data.listtoken().attr()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```